# Getting avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to vuejs and I am trying to sync **active** data to parent but getting an error as

> ***vue.js:523 [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "active" 
>   (found in component )***

My Vuejs Code is as below

```
<div id="app">
    <pre>
        {{$data}}
    </pre>
    <div v-for="plan in plans">
        <plan :plan="plan" :active.sync="active"></plan>
    </div>
</div>
<template id="mytemplate">
    <div>
        {{$data}}
        <span>{{plan.name}}</span>
        <span>{{plan.price}}</span>
        <button @click="setActivePlan">upgrade</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script src="vue.js"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",

        data: {
            active:this.active,
            plans: [
                {name: 'Diamond', price: '1000'},
                {name: 'Gold', price: '500'},
                {name: 'Silver', price: '250'},
                {name: 'Free', price: '0'}
            ]
        },
        components: {
            plan: {
                template: "#mytemplate",
                props: ['plan', 'active'],
                methods: {
                    setActivePlan: function () {
                        this.active = this.plan
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });
</script>
```

Can any one help me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is the version problem. please show your VUEJS version, else get the version from below code.

```
<div id="app">
    <pre>
    {{$data |  json}}
    </pre>
        <div v-for="plan in plans">
            <plan :plan="plan" :active.sync="active"></plan>
        </div>
    </div>
    <template id="mytemplate">
        <div>
            <span>{{plan.name}}</span>
            <span>{{plan.price}}</span>
            <span>a{{plan.active}}</span>
            <button @click="setActivePlan">upgrade</button>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.25/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: "#app",

            data: {
                plans: [
                    {name: 'Diamond', price: '1000'},
                    {name: 'Gold', price: '500'},
                    {name: 'Silver', price: '250'},
                    {name: 'Free', price: '0'}
                ],
                active:{

                }
            },
            components: {
                plan: {
                    template: "#mytemplate",
                    props: ['plan', 'active'],
                    methods: {
                        setActivePlan: function () {
                            this.active = this.plan
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 5):

As the error suggests, you are trying to change one of the props `active`.

> Prop being mutated: "active" (found in component )

As props are dynamically sent from parent, they will change whenever parent changes those, if you change them in child also, there will be conflict, thats why you are getting this error.

As par the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components):

> the parent-child component relationship can be summarized as props down, events up. The parent passes data down to the child via props, and the child sends messages to the parent via events.

So the proper way to do this will be to [emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit) an event, which will call a method in parent and change the variable `active` in parent where it is defined. Following will be the code changes:

```
<script src="vue.js"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",

        data: {
            active:this.active,
            plans: [
                {name: 'Diamond', price: '1000'},
                {name: 'Gold', price: '500'},
                {name: 'Silver', price: '250'},
                {name: 'Free', price: '0'}
            ]
        },
        methods: {
           setActivePlan: function (plan) {
              this.active = plan
           }
        } 
        components: {
            plan: {
                template: "#mytemplate",
                props: ['plan', 'active'],
                methods: {
                    setActivePlan: function () {
                        this.$emit('setActivePlan', this.plan)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: This explanation is much clearer than the documentation. VueJS is simply implementing the MVVM paradigm by not allowing upward mutation of property values.